# Illegal base64url character: ' ' while extracting the information from JWT token

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, base64, base64url

When trying to decode the JWT Tokens to extract the information from the token getting the Error
like

Illegal base64url character: ' '

This is my service class, when trying to execute the claims there is no output and error is thrown

I am trying to validate the user for that i have generated jwt token while loggin and when I am trying to use different services where user need to be verified I want to extract user information from JWT token and match it with database

````
package com.example.RentCar.Services;

import java.security.Key;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;

import com.example.RentCar.DTOS.UserRequestDTO;
import com.example.RentCar.Models.User;
import com.example.RentCar.Repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import io.jsonwebtoken.io.Decoders;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;

@Service
public class JwtServicesImpl implements JwtServices {
    private UserRequestDTO userRequestDTO;
    //private final UserRepository userRepository;
   // @Value("${token.signing.key}")
    private String jwtSigningKey = "413F4428472B4B6250655368566D5970337336763979244226452948404D6351";


    @Override
    public String extractUserName(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }
    @Override
    public String generateToken(User user) {
        return generateToken(new HashMap<>(), user);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean isTokenValid(String token, UserServicesImpl userServices) {
        final String email = extractUserName(token);
        UserDetails user = (userServices.loadUserByUsername(email));
        String email2 = user.getUsername();
        return (email.equals(email2) && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }
    private <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolvers) {
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        System.out.println(claims); //not printing
        return claimsResolvers.apply(claims);
    }

    private String generateToken(Map<String, Object> extraClaims, User user) {

        return Jwts.builder().setClaims(extraClaims).setSubject(user.getUserEmail())
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 24))
                .signWith(getSigningKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256).compact();
    }
    private boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    private Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(getSigningKey()).build().parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
    }

    private Key getSigningKey() {
       // System.out.println(jwtSigningKey);
        byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(jwtSigningKey);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }
}
```
below is the error

io.jsonwebtoken.io.DecodingException: Illegal base64url character: ' '
    at io.jsonwebtoken.io.Base64.ctoi(Base64.java:221)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.io.Base64.decodeFast(Base64.java:270)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.io.Base64Decoder.decode(Base64Decoder.java:36)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.io.Base64Decoder.decode(Base64Decoder.java:23)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.io.ExceptionPropagatingDecoder.decode(ExceptionPropagatingDecoder.java:36)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:288)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:529)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(DefaultJwtParser.java:589)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.ImmutableJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(ImmutableJwtParser.java:173)
    at com.example.RentCar.Services.JwtServicesImpl.extractAllClaims(JwtServicesImpl.java:76)
    at com.example.RentCar.Services.JwtServicesImpl.extractClaim(JwtServicesImpl.java:55)
    at com.example.RentCar.Services.JwtServicesImpl.extractUserName(JwtServicesImpl.java:34)
    at com.example.RentCar.Controllers.UserController.ModifyAddress(UserController.java:36)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)

Expecting should be like can claims or extract information from token
````

Comment: `jwtSigningKey` looks like it's hex, not base64... (I find it highly improbable that it's a string which *happens* to only contain 0-9, A-F, but is actually intended to be base64. )

Comment: jwtSigningKey is Hexa but the token which is generted is base64, right so does jwtSigningKey make any impact?

Comment: Well yes, because you're trying to decode it as if it's base64: `Decoders.BASE64.decode(jwtSigningKey)`. Don't do that...

Comment: So what should i do?

Comment: Well if you want your `keyBytes` to represent the data stored in `jwtSigningKey` in hex, then decode it as hex... that might not be the *only* problem with the code, but it looks like a pretty clear one.

Comment: For the human reader of the code, it's obvious that the key is hex encoded. But technically, the base64 decoder has no problem accepting it as base64 code. All characters from the hex code are valid base64 characters and 64 characters are a valid length for base64 without padding. I don't think the base64 decoding of the hex key caused the error.

Comment: Yes I agree with you that Hex is subset of base64 and I have verified that token is authentic so what could be the possible error then?

Answer (score 1):

As Jon Skeet said, your jwtSigningKey is encoded in Hex and in getSigningKey() you're telling Java to decode it with Base64.

Either have the key encoded with Base64 or decode with Hex.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/140861/21538342

Comment: See my comment above, under the question.

Comment: I tried decoding it in Hexa also but no benefit

When I am printing token it is coming 
Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJzZHA0NUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE3MDA4ODIzNjUsImV4cCI6MTcwMDg4MzgwNX0.LJFQo9r5dTYhW8v1cvrsToJc1yu0uMQcDGjiLAFCkUM

Comment: @Max that's probably the problem. You have to remove the word 'bearer' and the whitespace before you decode the token.